# How do i hide a form after submission is succesfull with Ajax/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello I've a  html form which validate by php with Ajax. After successfully insert all data to db it's show a Successfull message on html form. But Now I want hide the hitml form when it's showing me Successfull message. Following is my Ajax code..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#form1").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: form.action,
            type: form.method,
            //async: false,
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            beforeSend : function (){
              $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false); 
            },
            success: function(response) {
            $('#info1').html(response);
            $(form).find('#form1').hide();

            //return false;

            setTimeout(function() {
            $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false); 
            location.reload();
            }, 5000 );  
            }            
        });
    },

        rules: {
            title: "required",
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            company: "required",
            position: "required",           

            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            },
             email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: "checkEmail.php",
                        type: "post"
                     }
                },
            topic: {
                required: "#newsletter:checked",
                minlength: 2
            },
            terms: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            title : "Required",
            firstname: "Required",
            lastname: "Required",
            position: "Required",
            company: "Required",

            password: {
                required: "Required",
                minlength: "password must be at least 8 characters long"
            },
              email: {
                    required: "Please Enter Email!",
                    email: "This is not a valid email!",
                    remote: "Email already in use!"
                },
            terms: "Required"
        }
    });


});
</script>
```

I'm using this code to hide the html form but it's don't hind.

```
 $(form).find('#form1').hide();
```

**Html form**

```
<div id="info1">
</div>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars("regProcess.php") ?>">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['fname'])) echo $_POST['fname']; ?>" class="tr" placeholder="First Name"/></td>
  </tr>
  <!--more field-->
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Register" class="submit_button"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('form1').style.display = 'none';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `.find()`, change to:

```
$(form).hide();
```

The variable `form` is your form object, so you can simply add a jQuery wrapper and call `.hide()`. By using `.find()` you are asking jQuery to look for another form within your form, which isn't right.

Comment: Oh Simple Solution. Great.

Comment: Hello I've another form in this same page... So if I use same will it work ? I use this but second form is not working..

Comment: To hide another form you will need to directly select it such as `$('#form2').hide();`, because `form` refers to the form being submitted.

Comment: Just Awesome Answer from You.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$("#form1").hide();
```

There is no need of **find** for hiding..

You can also use **CSS** style property..

```
document.getElementById('form1').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: There is no need to traverse the DOM again to find `#form1`. `$(form)` is still accessible in the `success` function. `$(form).hide()` will be the same without traversing through the DOM again.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
$("#form1").css("display","none");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        url: form.action,
        type: form.method,
        //async: false,
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        beforeSend : function (){
          $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false); 
        },
        success: function(response) {
        $('#info1').html(response);
        $('#form1').hide();

        //return false;

        setTimeout(function() {
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false); 
        location.reload();
        }, 5000 );  
        }            
    });
```

Comment: There is no need to traverse the DOM again to find `#form1`. `$(form)` is accessible in the `success` function. `$(form).hide()` will work without traversing through the DOM again.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `$(from).hide();` instead of `$(form).find('#form1').hide();`  once you get response from ajax call, your existing form will hide.

Comment: `$(this)` won't work as you are inside the success function closure. In which `this` is the ajax object. `$(form).hide()` should work as `form` is defined in the outer scope and is still available.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `$('#form1').hide();` directly. That should work. Just be wary that it will be visible again when the page reloads in 5000 milliseconds. If that doesn't work, then there must be something else going on because what you have up there should work.

Answer (score 0):

The form object and the #form1 that u try to find, are the same element, you must use:

```
$('#form1').hide();
```

or try:

```
$(form).hide();
```